# How should I replicate the functionality of C#'s 'using' statement in Java?

Tags: c#, java, try-catch, using-statement, try-catch-finally

I'm converting some C# code to Java and it contains the `using` statement. How should I replicate this functionality in Java? I was going to use a `try`, `catch`, `finally` block but I thought I'd check with you guys first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard idiom for resource handling in Java is:

```
final Resource resource = acquire();
try {
    use(resource);
} finally {
    resource.dispose();
}
```

Common mistakes include trying to share the same `try` statement with exception catching and following on from that making a mess with `null`s and such.

The [Execute Around Idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341971/what-is-the-execute-around-idiom) can extract constructs like this, although the Java syntax is verbose.

```
executeWith(new Handler() { public void use(Resource resource) {
    ...
}});
```

Comment: Java 7 now has try-with-resources on Closable objects - an analog to using on IDisposable objects.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Answer (score 8):

That's correct.  A C# using block is just syntactic sugar for that anyway.  The closest Java equivalent to IDisposable is [`Closeable`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html).

There is a proposal (which is partially committed already), called [Automatic Resource Management](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/coin-dev/2009-February/000011.html), for adding similar functionality to Java 7.  It would use try-finally behind the scenes, and proposes creating a new Disposable interface (which would be a superinterface of Closeable).

Comment: ARM is now in so it's not a proposal anymore: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/tl/jdk/rev/c4d60bcce958

Comment: Technically I think just the API support for ARM is in, but the rest is coming.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget the null checking!
That is to say

```
using(Reader r = new FileReader("c:\test")){
    //some code here
}
```

should be translated to something like

```
Reader r = null;
try{
    //some code here
}
finally{
    if(r != null){
         r.close()
    }
}
```

And also most close() in java throw exceptions, so check 
[DbUtils.closeQuietly](http://commons.apache.org/dbutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbutils/DbUtils.html#closeQuietly(java.sql.Connection)) if you want your code to be more c# like

Comment: Guava's Closables is another option as the class is more generic than DbUtils.