# JDK 6 does not support Statement and ResultSet. What can I use instead of these?

Tags: java, resultset

I want to use

```
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

.
.
.


 try (Statement stmt = connection.createStatement()) {

               try (ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery(url)) {
                    while (rset.next()) { 
                    System.out.println (rset.getString(1)); 
                        }
                }
           }
```

in jdk 6. But it says that this is not supported. What can I do?

Comment: Is this real code snippet? It won't compile. Can you please post the import statements also?

Comment: I don't think it's the Statement or ResultSet, it's the try/catch blocks.  try { <statement> } catch (<exception type> e) { <statement> }

Comment: ooo :( yes it s because of try catch . when i deleted it works. answer and I tick it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's try-with-resource which is a new feature in Java SE 7. In Java SE 6 (recently had a life extension into next year, but I wouldn't write new code for it):

```
Statement stmt = connection.createStatement() {
try {
    ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery(url)
    try {
        while (rset.next()) { 
            System.out.println (rset.getString(1)); 
        }
    } finally {
        rset.close();
    }
} finally {
    stmt.close();
}
```

You can use the [Execute Around idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341971/what-is-the-execute-around-idiom) to factor out to repetitive bits.

Answer (score 1):

[Try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) is a feature introduced with Java 7. You need to manage your resources by hand.

```
Statement stmt = null;
ResultSet rset = null;
try {
   stmt = connection.createStatement();
   rset =  stmt.executeQuery(url);
   while (rset.next()) { 
      System.out.println(rset.getString(1)); 
   }
} catch (Exception e) {
   // In your real code catch expecific exceptions and do something about it.
} finally {
   if (rset != null) {
       try { 
          rset.close(); 
       } catch (Exception e) {} // Same thing 
   }
   if (stmt != null) {
       try {
          stmt.close();
       } catch (Exception e) {} // Same thing 
   }
}
```

Alternatively use a library such as [Apache dbutils](http://commons.apache.org/dbutils/) or better yet [Spring Framework JDBC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html) to avoid the boilerplate code.