# Dealing with code duplication of acquiring resources in try...finally blocks

Tags: java

I'm working with a database in Java and have been writing multiple functions along the lines of

```
try {
    //acquire resources
}
finally {
    //release resources
}
```

I know that Java's try-with-resources is a decent way to deal with something like this, but I'm using Java 6.  Is there a standard way to reduce code duplication?  I'd love to have a clean way of writing multiple functions which have the same try/finally blocks for resource allocation, but whose body differs.

My current thought was to make the bodies of the function members of a class whose constructor acquires the resources.  But, without RAII, it seems a bit messy still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **aspects**. The great example of aspects in work is the **Spring** framework. One of the features that is realized in that way is the **transaction support**. The transactional aspects are handling the transaction opening , committing (on normal proceed) or rollbacking (on exception), and releasing in each case.

Answer (score 3):

If you can afford to use Guava (14.0+), you can use [`Closer`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Closer.html). While it does not eliminate *all* duplication, it is a very convenient way to deal with resources implementing `Closeable` -- and more than one, at that:

```
final Closer closer = Closer.create();
final InputStream in1;
final InputStream in2; // whatever, as long as Closeable is implemented

try {
    in1 = closer.register(createIn1());
    in2 = closer.register(createIn2());
    // do stuff
} finally {
    closer.close();
}
```

This class will handle the closing of all resources gracefully, and in the reverse order in which you registered them.

If you cannot afford Guava, it is quite easy to code a simple version of it yourself.

Comment: The xUnit Design Patterns book describes a similar way of closing resources using `@After` methods in JUnit.

Comment: @fge, following your comments I did a bit of reading re. `Closer`. In [the documentation](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ClosingResourcesExplained) they state _it's very important to follow the prescribed usage pattern_. It doesn't look like  you're following the pattern (notably _any Throwable thrown from the block where the Closeable resources are used must be caught and rethrown through Closer's rethrow method_).

Comment: @BoristheSpider this is for exceptions other than IOExceptions (therefore all throwables inheriting IOException as well)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Project Lombock](http://projectlombok.org/); it uses annotation processing to tidy up boilerplate.

More specifically you can use the [@Cleanup](http://projectlombok.org/features/Cleanup.html) annotation and it will wrap in `try...finally` at compile time.

So your code goes from

```
final Connection con...
try {
    //do stuff
} finally {
    con.close();
}
```

To

```
@Cleanup
final Connection con...
```

Both will compile to *the same code*.

Comment: The problem with lombok in general is that it is fine when you see the original code; but the generated code can become quite ungainly... Especially with this annotation ;)

Comment: @fge, yes - applying the most generic rules does result in somewhat ugly code, but it shouldn't impact on performance and you don't _see_ the ugly code. The JIT compiler doesn't care if the code is pretty or not. I admit I find myself writing lots of unit tests for things like this however to ensure that the generated code works correctly.

Comment: Well, you _do_ see the ugly code when you want to debug a library using it and want to debug the source.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the Execute Around idiom describes exactly this use case - [What is the "Execute Around" idiom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341971/what-is-the-execute-around-idiom)

However, it seems a bit messy to implement