# Exception-safely return Autoclosable object

Tags: java, autocloseable

When you want to use some `AutoClosable` object you should use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). Ok. But what if I want to write a method, that returns an `AutoClosable`? After you've created or received an AutoCloseable object, you should close it in case of exception, like this:

```java
    public static AutoCloseable methodReturningAutocloseable() {
        AutoCloseable autoCloseable = ... // create some AutoClosable
        try {
            ... // some work
        }
        catch (Throwable exception) {
            autoCloseable.close();
            throw exception;
        }
        return autoCloseable;
    }
```

If you don't write `try/catch` block you would leak the resource, that autoCloseable object holds, in case of exception in `// some work` line.
But this `try/catch` is not enough, because `autoCloseable.close()` can throw exception too (by design). So, the above code transforms to

```java
    public static AutoCloseable methodReturningAutocloseable() {
        AutoCloseable autoCloseable = ... // create some autoclosable
        try {
            ... // some work
        }
        catch (Throwable exception) {
            try {
                autoCloseable.close();
            }
            catch (Throwable exceptionInClose) {
                exception.addSuppressed(exceptionInClose);
                throw exception;
            }
            throw exception;
        }
        return autoCloseable;
    }
```

That's a lot of boilerplate. Is there a better way to do it in java?

Comment: The question would be why you want to return the `autoclosable`?, since it would already be closed at the return statement.

Comment: @Kiskae why it would be closed at the return statement in the example code above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of approached.

- Use the [Execute Around idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/q/341971/4725). Reformulate the interface to ease client implementation and remove the problem.
- Ignore the problem. Sounds silly, but that's generally what happens when wrapping with I/O stream decorators.
- Wrap inside a proxy `AutoCloseable` and put that in your try-with-resource.
- Write out the equivalent of try-with-resource use try-catch and try-finally. (I wouldn't - nasty.)
- Write a modified try-with-resource as a library feature. This code would become the client of the Execute Around.
- Write the exception handling old school style with try-catch and try-finally.

**Edit:** I thought I'd revisit the answer adding some example code for fun.

**Execute Around idiom**

The simple and best solution. Unfortunately the Java library does not use it much (`AccessController.doPrivileged` is a big exception) and conventions are not well established. As ever Java's checked exceptions without supporting features make things tricky. We can't use `java.util.function` and have to invent our own functional interfaces.

```
// Like Consumer, but with an exception.
interface Use<R, EXC extends Exception> {
    void use(R resource) throws EXC;
}

public static void withThing(String name, Use<InputStream,IOException> use) throws IOException {
     try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(name)) {
         use.use(in);
     }
}
```

Nice and simple. No need to worry about client code messing up the resource handling as it doesn't do it. Nice.

**A modified try-with-resource as a library feature implemented as a proxy `AutoCloseable` in a try-with-resource**

It's going to get ugly. We need to pass acquisition, release and the initialisation as lambdas. Creating the resource directly within this method opens up a small window where an unexpected exception would lead to a leak.

```
public static InputStream newThing(String name) throws IOException {
    return returnResource(
        () -> new FileInputStream(name),
        InputStream::close,
        in -> {
            int ignore = in.read(); // some work
        }
    );
}
```

The general implementation of `returnResource` is going to look like this hack below. A hack because try-with-resource doesn't support this sort of thing and Java library doesn't support checked exceptions well. Note limited to one exception (you can use an unchecked exception for no checked exceptions).

```
interface Acquire<R, EXC extends Exception> {
    R acquire() throws EXC;
}
// Effectively the same as Use, but different.
interface Release<R, EXC extends Exception> {
    void release(R resource) throws EXC;
}

public static <R, EXC extends Exception> R returnResource(
    Acquire<R, EXC> acquire, Release<R, EXC> release, Use<R, EXC> initialize
) throws EXC {
    try (var adapter = new AutoCloseable() { // anonymous classes still define type
        private R resource = acquire.acquire();
        R get() {
            return resource;
        }
        void success() {
            resource = null;;
        }
        public void close() throws EXC {
           if (resource != null) {
               release.release(resource);
           }
        }
    }) {
        R resource = adapter.get();
        initialize.use(resource);
        adapter.success();
        return resource;
    }
}
```

This is perhaps cleaner if we separate out the argument we are constructing the resource with from the construction of the resource.

```
public static InputStream newThing(String name) throws IOException {
    return returnResource(
        name,
        FileInputStream::new,
        InputStream::close,
        in -> {
            int ignore = in.read(); // some work
        }
    );
}

// Like Function, but with a more descriptive name for a functional interface.
interface AcquireFrom<T, R, EXC extends Exception> {
    R acquire(T t) throws EXC;
}

public static <T, R, EXC extends Exception> R returnResource(
    T t, AcquireFrom<T, R, EXC> acquire, Release<R, EXC> release, Use<R, EXC> initialize
 ) throws EXC {
     return returnResource(() -> acquire.acquire(t), release, initialize);
 }
```

So in summary, the following things are a pain:

- Transferring resource ownership. Keep it local.
- `java.util.function` doesn't support checked exceptions.
- The Java library not supporting Execute Around.
- `AutoCloseable::close` declaring that it throws `Exception` instead of the being a type parameter of the type.
- Checked exceptions without sum types.
- The Java language syntax in general.