# null check in try-with-resources

Tags: java, try-catch, try-with-resources, null-check, sonarcloud

I've got the following code:

```
try (Connection connection = getConnection();

    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(someSql)) {//stuff}
```

How do I check that connection is not null here?

Also, I got a method which returns a PreparedStatement like this:

```
private PreparedStatement getPreparedStatement(Connection connection)

  throws SQLException {

PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL);

preparedStatement.setString(1, "someString");

return preparedStatement;

}
```

this gets called within a method that uses the following try with resources:

```
try (Connection connection = getConnection();
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement =
        getPreparedStatement(connection)) {//stuff}
```

Now I would assume the prepared statement will be autoclosed, because it gets initiated in the try with resources. But SonarCloud says that i should use try with resources in the getPreparedStatement-method or close that PreparedStatement in a finally block. Is this a wrong finding by SonarCloud or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: So is this two separate questions?  As in the first block of code is a different question from the rest?

Comment: Definitely a wrong finding by SonarCloud.  And it’s far from the first.  Code analysis tools are hard to write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getConnection` should throw an exception instead of returning `null`. Returning `null` is not nice`. SonarCloud seems to be wanting you to put a try-with-resource opening in`getPreparedStatement`(must include the`setString`) and closing in the calling method, which of course you can't do as such.

The best approach is the [Execute Around idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/q/341971/4725). Instead of `getPreparedStatement` returning a `PreparedStatement` pass in a lambda (typically) to be executed. The resource can then be closed in a try-with-resource statement cleanly.

```
/*** NICE ***/
// Function instead of Consumer would allow the method to return a value.
private void prepared(
    Connection connection, Consumer<PreparedStatement> op
) throws SQLException {
    // Might want to add getConnection in here too, perhaps.
    try (
        PreparedStatement statement =
             connection.prepareStatement(SQL)
    ) { 
        statement.setString(1, "someString");
        op.accept(statement);
    }
}
```

Used as:

```
    try (Connection connection = getConnection()) {
        prepared(connection, statement -> {
            // blah, blah, blah
        });
    }
```

The hacky alternative is to include a try statement within `getPreparedStatement` that only closed in error conditions.

```
/*** HACKY ***/
private PreparedStatement prepared(
    Connection connection
) throws SQLException {
    boolean success = false;
    PreparedStatement statement =
        connection.prepareStatement(SQL);
    try { 
        statement.setString(1, "someString");
        success = true;
        return preparedStatement;
    } finally {
        if (!success) {
            statement.close();
        }
    }
}
```

If you desperately want `getConnection` to return `null` (don't) and use a single two-entry try-with-resource, then the conditional operator works.

```
try (
    Connection connection = getConnection();
    PreparedStatement statement =
        connection==null ? null : connection.prepareStatement(SQL)
) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest approch and IMO the most readable one would be to use 2 try-with-resources blocks. Even sonar has an built-in exception from disallowing nested try-catch-blocks for exactly this use case...

```
try (Connection conn = getConnection()) {
    if (conn != null) {
        try (PreparedStatement stmt = ...) {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

If `do stuff` is lengthy, it could and should be refactored into a separate method (possibly including the inner try-with-resources).

Comment: this is what I came up with too, but is it really good practice?

Comment: I've seen and used it in several projects and companies. I've seen and had it in many code reviews without complaints and if even sonar has a special rule allowing it (it generally discourages nested try-catch-blocks), I think it's at least a good enough aproach for me until I see a better one. One improvement would be to prevent getConnection from returning null.

Comment: `getConnection` should *never* return null.