# try with resources in a method used by another one

Tags: java, try-catch

I have the following java code with try with resources:

```
public static CloseableHttpResponse getHttpResponse()
    {
        try (CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build()) {
            try (CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(request)) {
                return response;
            }
        }
    }
```

in another method will use the `response` returned by `getHttpResponse`:

```
public void test() {
        CloseableHttpResponse response = getHttpResponse();
        if (response) {
            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                // do something
            }
        }
    }
```

Looks like after `CloseableHttpResponse response = getHttpResponse();`, the `client` and `response` already closed, and I can not put this two methods into one, are there any ways that still use the try with resources in another method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach is the [Execute Around idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/q/341971/4725). Instead of `getHttpResponse` returning a `CloseableHttpResponse` pass in a lambda (typically) to be executed. The resource can then be closed in a try-with-resource statement cleanly.

```
/*** NICE ***/
// Function instead of Consumer would allow the method to return a value.
private void httpResponse(
    Consumer<CloseableHttpResponse> op
) /* throws IOException */ {
    try (CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build()) {
        try (CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(request)) {
            if (response != null) { // Really?
                op.accept(response);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Used as:

```
    httpResponse(response -> {
        int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            // do something
        }
    });
```

The hacky alternative is to include a try statement within `getHttpResponse` that only closed in error conditions.

```
/*** HACKY ***/
private CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse() /* throws IOException */ {
    boolean success = false;
    CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    try {
        CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        try {
            success = true;
            return response;
        } finally {
            if (!success) {
                response.close();
            }
        }
    } finally {
        if (!success) {
            client.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`client` will be closed as soon as the program leaves the scope of the try-with-resources. Can you try building the try with resources around the getHttpResponse method? For example:

```
public static CloseableHttpResponse getHttpResponse() {
    try (CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build()) {
        CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(request)
        return response;
    }
}
```

And then you can rewrite your test method() like this:

```
public void test() {
    try(CloseableHttpResponse response = getHttpResponse()) {
        if (response) {
            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                // do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In this way, when client is closed as the program out of the try-with-resources, can the response is still valid?

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but my guess is that the response would no longer be valid because response is a stream over the content from the network socket